# How to change the data type of multiple Excel cells to Single?

Tags: r, vba, excel

I am new to VBA but experienced in R. In my current project I need to read in a lot of spreadsheets which is slow!

Basically I have an Excel-sheet of numeric columns. I checked what data type they are:

```
Public Sub cellType()
       MsgBox TypeName(Range("A1").Value)
End Sub
```

Turns out most of them are of [type DOUBLE](https://www.promotic.eu/en/pmdoc/Subsystems/Db/Excel/DataTypes.htm). Since I have about 40 sheets to read into R, I wondered whether I can just change all numeric values to SINGLE type. However with the following nothing changes.

```
Public Sub changeDType()
       Range("A2").Value = CSng(Range("A2").Value)
       Range("B5").Select
End Sub
```

The value from `A2` stay as `DOUBLE`. Is there any way to change them to single?

In addition I would like to do this for all columns (e.g. like `Range("A2:H500")`). But then I get an error. Is there a way to change this for whole column?

Edit: The idea behind this question was to speed up the `readxl` command by converting the DOUBLE stored numeric vectors into SINGLE and thereby getting rid of a lot of these numbers after the dot which DOUBLE stores. After all R only handles about 16 numbers after the dot. In addition I hoped to save several lines of code by using `readxl` over `read_csv`.

Edit2: Since there is apparently no way around the csv, I [generated the csv without opening Excel](http://housesofstones.github.io/2013/06/18/quickly-read-excel-worksheets-into-r-windows-only-sorry/) (works only for windows, apparently).

Comment: Depending on the precision of your data, I wouldn't recommend changing the data type. For instance, if you take the put the value `1.123456789` into cell A1, then run `Range("A2").Value = CSng(Range("A1").Value)` you'll notice that the value changes to be `1.123456836`. It may be better to look into alternate methods of importing the data in R to improve efficiency to avoid potential corruption of data.

Comment: If you are using `XLConnect` to read the data in R, I would recommend trying to use something like `readxl` instead, which tends to import data much faster.

Comment: You cannot change type of data (numeric data) in excel cells. That type can be defined for values within VBA, AFAIK. `readxl` is a good option, but still reading them as text files or csv as proposed by the answer using `readr::read_csv` is faster in orders of magnitude.

Comment: Thanks @Matt. Didnt know about the corrupting part. I thought it would just save less numbers after the dot. I already use `readxl`. But when you read multiple sheets in, it is slow as well. At the moment my method of choice is converting all sheets to csv. But this is a bit messy.

Comment: For the record, as I said in the comment below, this looks like an [XY Proble](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You can ask how to do the *"automation stuff"* in R sufficiently and stick to `read_csv` as it is way faster than `readxl`.

Comment: I know how to automate it with csv, but before I go down that path I wanted to know whether there is an easier/simpler way using `readxl`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot convert it to something like `Single`. Even if you have an integer value, the type is double:

```
Sub testValue()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Cells(1, 1)
    r.Value = 5
    MsgBox TypeName(r.Value)
End Sub
```

I don't know how you read Excel data into R, but I don't think that the datatype itself is slowing down the process. Maybe it's faster if you save the worksheets as CSV and import them?

Comment: yes it is. I am already doing that. With csv it is about 1.8 seconds with `readxl`it is about 7 seconds. The issue is that with csv it is more difficult to automate stuff. Therefore the idea of speeding up things in excel.

Comment: @5th *automate stuff* like what? This looks like an XY Problem. Ask about those stuff and how to do them sufficiently in R.

Comment: @Masoud I think this XY Problem is a rather subjective categorisation. Nevertheless I edited the question and described why I asked it. I find your suggestion misleading because it turns the whole issue into a meta question about person asking the question. After all the purpose of this place is to answer question, not to open fuzzy new ones.

Comment: @5th maybe subjective, but as a personal opinion when you have problem (it's slow) with importing excel files into R and you ask about how to change the data type to make it faster, I categorize your question into XY problems. Again, personal opinion. Glad that you found an answer and got help. And I would say don't get offended by comments unless they are obviously offensive. Otherwise, most of the time people are trying to help. Cheers.